Calling static method in LINQ Where clause
I have the following LINQ expression:
IList<string> names = ["Doe_John", "Doe_Jane"];
queryable = queryable.Where(x => names.Contains(Name.Combine(x.person.LastName, x.person.FirstName)));

During runtime it throws exception

The LINQ expression ... could not be translated

It seems that LINQ is unable to parse the static method invocation.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Best regards,
Setnug

What is Name.Combine ?

It cannot translate to the SQL Name.Combine - replace with just concatenation.

Name.Combine is simply concatenating first & last name with _ as separator. I prefer to call the method instead since it's called everywhere. So if there's a need to change the separator I only have to do it in 1 place.

Without third party extensions it is not possible. EF cannot look into compiled method body and understand that this is "just concatenation".

First some short tests to find out the cause of your problems, then a description of why you got the problem.
Spoiler: I think the problem is in your own method Name.Combine(string, string)
Some debugging with test code
Although you forgot to say so I think that queryable contains an IQueryable sequence of similar items, where every Item contains a property Person, and every Person has propertyies FirstName and LastName, probably both strings.
You want to query only those items that have a Person with a full name that is in sequence names. In simple words: you only want the Persons named John or Jane Doe.
Your Where uses two extension methods: Queryable.Contains and String.Combine. I can't find the latter method, so it's probably a method of your own.
Consider to add such information to your next question, so we won't have to extract this from your code.
Try the following:
IList<string> names = ["Doe_John", "Doe_Jane"];
string[] testNames= ["John", "Jane"];
var test1 = queryable.Where(x => x.Person.FirstName == "John")
    .Take(10).ToList();
var test2 = queryable.Where(x => testNames.Contains(x.Person.FirstName))
    .Take(10).ToList();
var test3 = queryable.Where(x => Name.Combine(x.Person.Lastname, x.Person.FirstName))
    .Take(10).ToList();

Add this to your code and start your debugger with breakpoints.
I added ToList(), to execute the query immediately, so you can check the results in your debugger. I added Take(10) to prevent fetching to many items.
My guess is that you will only see problems in test3, the query where you use your own method.
Why can Name.Combine not be translated?
For this you'll have to understand the difference between an IEnumerable and an IQueryable.
IEnumerable
An IEnumerable<...> represents a sequence of similar items. It holds everything to ask for every element of the sequence one by one.
You can ask for the first element, and as long as you've got an element, you can ask for the next one, as long as there is a next one.
At its lowest level, this is done using GetEnumerator, MoveNext and Current:
IEnumerable<T> sequence = ...
using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator())
{
    // Get the first / next element.
    // MoveNext returns false if there is no element anymore
    While(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // There is an item in the sequence, process it:
        T item = enumerator.Current;
        Process(item);
    }
}

statements like foreach and all LINQ methods that don't return IEnumerable<...>, like ToList, ToDictionary, Count, FirstOrDefault, Any, etc, use deep inside GetEnumerator / MoveNext / Current.
IQueryable
An IQueryable<...> looks very much like an IEnumerable, however, it doesn't represent an enumerable sequence, it represents the potential to fetch an enumerable sequence.
To be able to fetch the enumerable sequence, the IQueryable holds an Expression and a Provider.
The Expression holds the data that must be queried in some generic format. The Provider knows who must provide the data (usually a Database Management System), and how to cummunicate with this DBMS (usually something like SQL).
As long as you concatenate LINQ methods that return IQueryable<...>, the query is not executed, there is no communication with the DBMS. Only the Expression is changed. Concatenating this kind of LINQ methods isn't costly.
As soon as you call one of the LINQ methods that don't return IQueryable<...>, like ToList(), the query is executed. Or to be more precise: as soon as GetEnumerator() is called, the Expression is sent to the Provider, who will translate it into SQL and execute the query. The fetched data will be returned as an Enumerator<...> of which you can call MoveNext and Current.
Some Providers are smarter, and will fetch the data at the first MoveNext, so it won't be fetched if you call GetEnumerator but decide not to enumerate the sequence.
Even smarter Providers won't fetch all data, but will fetch it per page, of, let's say 100 items. So if yo call Take(10).ToList(), not all 2000 items are fetched. If during enumeration the page of fetched items becomes empty, the next MoveNext fetches the next page of 100 items.
But what has this to do with my problem?
Your Provider doesn't know your own defined methods like Name.Combine(string, string). Therefor the compiler can't translate this method into SQL. In fact, there are several standard LINQ methods that are not supported by Linq to entities. See Supported and unsupported LINQ methods
Your compiler doesn't know how smart your Provider is, the compiler can't complain that you are using unsupported methods. You'll see the error at runtime.
How to solve it.
I don't know your method Name.Combine(string, string), but I think it concatenates LastName and FirstName with an underscore in between.
Consider to use string contatenation:
var result = queryable
    .Where(item => names.Contains(
        item.person.LastName + "_" + item.person.FirstName))
    .ToList();

If you need this construction more often, consider to create an extension method. If you are not familiar with extension methods, consider to read Extension Methods Demystified
static bool ContainsPersonName(this IQueryable<string> source, Person person)
{
    return Queryable.Contains(source, person.LastName + "_" + person.FirstName);
}

Usage:
IQueryable<string> availablePersons = ["Doe_John", "Doe_Jane"].AsQueryable();
Person p = new Person {FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", ...};

bool personIsAvailabe = names.ContainsPersonName(p);

Or in your case:
IQueryable<string> names = ["Doe_John", "Doe_Jane"].AsQueryable();
var result = queryable.Where(item => names.ContainsPersonName(item.person))
                      .ToList();

My advice would be to create only the extension method if you really think that others would find it useful. After all, a knew method needs knowledge by others, it needs unit tests, it must be mainained etc. Only bother to do this if the method will be used several times.
